# How to improve performance of the dynamically build SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-performance

Actually I'm a little bit stuck with the problem when we have a dynamically created SQL by our java code, that means there is no consistency in the list of fields used in where clause to put the proper index there is a huge delays and performance loses. We are using MSSql server as a storage of historical data. Total amount of records at the moment 3 millions and will be increased for sure. Is there a way to optimize the following SQL queries. Any help will be very much appreciated, since I can't add indexes to all possible combinations of fields there are 10+.

```
SELECT
  F_ID,
  F_2,
  F_3,..., F_15 FROM T_1 WHERE ~dynamically changed~
UNION ALL
SELECT
  F_ID,
  F_2,
  F_3,..., F_15 FROM T_2 WHERE ~dynamically changed~
ORDER BY F_ID OFFSET 75 ROWS FETCH NEXT 25 ROWS ONLY`

`SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT F_ID
      FROM T_1
      WHERE ~dynamically changed~
      UNION ALL SELECT F_ID
                FROM T_2
                WHERE ~dynamically changed~) clause
```

Right now I have the only index ~ clustered ID index. It doesn't help much.

Comment: A clustered index doesn't help very much when trying to filter data. Especially when you're trying to filter the data by any other column that is not the (or part of) clustering key. I recommend you investigate what are the possible columns in your `~dynamically changed~` filters and create non-clustered indexes for those columns.

Comment: Not sure about the first query however you can improve your second query by rewriting as -    SELECT SUM(CNT)
FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) CNT
      FROM T_1
      WHERE ~dynamically changed~
      UNION ALL SELECT COUNT(*)  CNT
                FROM T_2
                WHERE ~dynamically changed~) clause

Comment: @RahulRichhariya thank you guys, i will try and update on the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what I've done to solve the issue, is

1. Created a couple of indexes with the most used and approximately unique fields included the rest of the fields used in filter, this prevents unnecessary inner joins to fetch the data in the where clause that is not a part of the index

   > CREATE INDEX IX_1 ON table_placeholder (F_1) INCLUDE (F_2, F_3, F_4);
   >   CREATE INDEX IX_2 ON table_placeholder (F_2) INCLUDE (F_1, F_3, F_4);
2. Changed the existing queries in order to let limit/filter operation be executed first and after that apply joins to the limited set of data. On this stage query plan is the only friend in your optimization. IN my particular example the newly created query looks like

   > WITH cte AS (
   >   SELECT id, tbl FROM (
   >           SELECT
   >               F_ID as id,
   >               1 AS tbl
   >       FROM T_1 WHERRE ~dynamically changed ~
   >       UNION ALL
   >       SELECT
   >           F_ID as id,
   >           2 AS tbl
   >       FROM T_2 WHERE ~dynamically changed ~) as t
   >   ORDER BY id
   >   OFFSET :offset ROWS FETCH NEXT :size ROWS ONLY)
   >   SELECT
   >       F_ID,
   >       F_2,
   >       F_3,..., F_15
   >   FROM cte
   >   INNER JOIN T_1 ON cte.id = F_ID AND tbl = 1
   >   UNION ALL
   >   SELECT
   >       F_ID,
   >       F_2,
   >       F_3,..., F_15
   >       FROM cte
   >       INNER JOIN T_2 ON cte.id = F_ID AND tbl = 2;

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more about the fields in question and the data in there this can't be answered in a good way, but here are some advices.

- You don't need to create combined indizes for 10+ fields, you can create an index containing each single field. That's easily possible but of course comes with more required space on the storage system. There are fields where an index doesn't make a lot of sense, e.g. fields containing only two different values (boolean, int fields used as boolean by containing the values `0` and `1`, etc.)
- Print out queries that turn out to be slow and analyse them with MS SQL's query analyser. There is a [TechNet article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191227(v=sql.105).aspx) at Microsoft explaining how to do that.
  With the information given you can decide about the best approach to optimize the query, i.e. what index needs to be added to speed things up.
- You seem to do the paging of the result within the SQL. You might check if this can be done within the programming language you're using for the presentation. In that case, you can open a cursor and iterate through the data making the execution of the statement necessary only once (the third statement that only calculates the number of all entries to show up comes with the cursor for free).

Comment: It's not bad to do paging within the database, it actually saves a lot of RAM, I/O, network time, CPU time, which is quite valuable for a DB. Also, sending more data across the wire than needed is the cause for slowness.

Comment: is a set of combined indexes wouldn't perform better then a separate indexes for all approximately unique fields? I mean I can create 4 separate indexes for 1, 2, 3, 4  + 2, 3, 4 + 3, 4 + 4 even if we pass a single 3 value or 2,3 values they'll be used by db engine right IN my understanding it covers more cases then just a single one.

Comment: @UladzislauKuzmin It might be better but it depends. An index on a single field is better than no index, so you should check if the "one index per single field" makes sense for you. Also as you yourself already said, with 10+ fields the number of combinations is simply too much to createall possible combinations. After creating indizes for the fields you can monitor your application for slow queries (not sure how you set that up in MS SQL but there should be something similar to MySQL's slow-query-log) and analyse that as described to decide on further optimaiztions (index, change of query...)